# How can I calculate the probality of to get a number with 15 digits lenght repeat

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

A number with nineteen digits is generated randomically by a particular system and it's guaranteed that every number generated is unique (by the system provider).

If I chunk this number and get the last fifteen digits, from right to the left, for example:

0123456789012345678 -> **456789012345678**

Assuming that this procedure will be repeat for undefined and unlimited times it's possible to verify if will be possible to get repeated number?  How would be the chance or the probability to get a repeated number in this new sub selection or subset?

How can I calculate this or explain mathematically this probability?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it extends for an unlimited time you are guaranteed to get a repeat.  You are guaranteed a repeat after $10^{15}+1$ trials.  In fact, the system will fail its promise to never repeat the whole number after $10^{19}+1$ trials.

The probability of a collision is a generalization of [the birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Cast_as_a_collision_problem).  The exact calculations get messy because you have a limited inventory of $15$ digit numbers- $10^4$ of each.  But if we ignore that, we are drawing from $d=10^{15}$ possibilities with replacement and asking for the number of draws to achieve a probability $p$ of a collision, we get $$n=\sqrt{2d \ln \left(\frac 1{1-p}\right)}$$  For $d=10^{15},p=\frac 12$ this gives about $3.73 \cdot 10^7$

The naive approach is that having drawn $n$ numbers you have $\frac {n(n-1)}2$ pairs, and each pair has $10^{-15}$ chance of matching.  This leads to $n \approx \sqrt {2d}$ which is quite close.

Comment: Thanks Very much Ross, you rocks! But are you considering a combination with repetition, I mean Crep(m,p) = C(m+p-1,p) because I can arrange C digitis {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} in p ways (15)  (012345678901234),(011111111111111) and so on?

Comment: I could consider the d value as binomial(24, 15) or the result of C(24,15) ?

Comment: @Bera:  yes, we are looking at with repetition because  there are $10$ choices at each location.  We are looking at $10{15}$ possibilities.  I presume $24$ comes from $15+10-1$ but that considers order unimportant.  We want to consider 000000999999999 different from 999999999000000